# React - Keep form information after getting a 401 response from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on a react application as a junior developer

When a user sends a form and the API sends back a 401 token expired, I want him to get redirected to login page (that is ok), but I want him to go to form page once he logs in again with the data he had filled before to get redirected to login page

I have an interceptor that logs the user out when a 401 code is returned from API, it triggers my auth service logout method, then my private route redirects to login page:

```
if (!isLoggedIn) {
  // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
  return (
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
  );
}
```

I want to redirects the user to props.location when he logs in back and to keep his data

Do you guys know any way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

401 - not authorized.

In case of logout user and management route you have **withrouter** + **history**

[In documentation:](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

> go(n) - (function) Moves the pointer in the history stack by n entries

Here is defined component for **goBack** - it's go **n(-1)** in history.
You can also define your logic in function

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReturnIcon from '../../img/tech/return-white-icon.svg'

const GoBack = ({ history }) => <img src={ReturnIcon} onClick={() => history.goBack()} alt="Go back" />;

export default withRouter(GoBack);
```

It's also important to remember - to redirect to an **authorized** route - prior **authentication** is required.

---

You can prevent losing your token:

> It may also have a validity period. Once this validity period has
>   elapsed, the server will no longer allow access to resources with this
>   token. In this step, the user will have to get a new access token by
>   reauthentication or with some additional method: refresh token.

There is a lot of [theory](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/refresh-token-in-web-api/), & [theory](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52/)

When you define **token** on backend-site, the one of optional parameters is **lifecycle** - for example token can be valid for 4h, and later disactive.

You need to read about tokens (refresh, accessibility etc.)

The one of possiblity is create refresh token on backend site - and call it from frontend

**Node.js:**

```
var refreshTokens = {} 
      var token = jwt.sign(user, SECRET, { expiresIn: 300 }) 
      var refreshToken = randtoken.uid(256) 
      refreshTokens[refreshToken] = username res.json({token: 'JWT ' + token, refreshToken: refreshToken})
```